# disappeared comment fields in content type, how to put them back

Tags: entities, comments

I'm working on a drupal page and recently encountered a problem when I couldn't enable comments on a certain content type. Looking for the problem I found that there were no fields for the comments in that content type.

I checked the other content types where comments were enabled without problems and checked which fields were enabled for the comments. 
I tried to enable the comments in the first content type by adding an existing field for comments, but the comment fields were not available to choose.

Here i attach an image of what it looks like on the drupal (It's in spanish but I hope you can get the context)
[image: How the content type looks like without comment fields]

This is how it should look like with the comment fields:
[image: How the content type looks like with the comment fields]

Is there a way to retrieve this fields so comments can be enabled for this content type?

Comment: Have you tried re-adding them by looking to see if they are listed in `Seleccione un campo existente` ?

Comment: Yes I tried, as I mentioned in the question, but the comment fields were not available to choose there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on the code for [`comment_field_extra_fields()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_field_extra_fields/7), I think that what you are noting can be explained with the `comment_subject_field_$type` persistent variable being set to a value different from 1. (`$type` is the machine name of the content type.)

```
function comment_field_extra_fields() {
  $return = array();

  foreach (node_type_get_types() as $type) {
    if (variable_get('comment_subject_field_' . $type->type, 1) == 1) {
      $return['comment']['comment_node_' . $type->type] = array(
        'form' => array(
          'author' => array(
            'label' => t('Author'),
            'description' => t('Author textfield'),
            'weight' => -2,
          ),
          'subject' => array(
            'label' => t('Subject'),
            'description' => t('Subject textfield'),
            'weight' => -1,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  return $return;
}
```

[`comment_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_form/7) contains the following code.

```
  $form['subject'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Subject'),
    '#maxlength' => 64,
    '#default_value' => $comment->subject,
    '#access' => variable_get('comment_subject_field_' . $node->type, 1) == 1,
    '#weight' => -1,
  );
```

Only when the `'comment_subject_field_' . $node->type` persistent variable is set to 1 the users have access to that form field.

Changing the value of that persistent variable to 1 should restore those form fields you are expecting to see.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow and I will tell you if this works. thank you.

Comment: I confirmed that it was the problem. It was solved by adding      `variable_set('comment_subject_field_' . $node->type, 1);` in the node type template.